# Cant connect to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Okay, I am trying to practice some commands in Oracle but I just connect before it, SQL has a mistake ORA-12557: TNS:protocol adapter not loadable and I literally don't know how to solve this. Its important to mention that I have already set SID as orcl [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CoDp.png)

Comment: Have you read this question, and it's answer?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426915/ora-12557-tnsprotocol-adapter-not-loadable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-12557 TNS:protocol adapter not loadable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426915/ora-12557-tnsprotocol-adapter-not-loadable)