# ORA-12557: Connecting ORACLE to modelling software (EMBLEM)

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to make a connection between Emblem and Oracle. I've already made a similar connection using R which works fine. The image below shows the environment variables that I am using. I also have set up a driver via ODBC Data Source Administrator. Again, this set up has worked fine when connecting to R using ROracle.

However, when I try to connect via Emblem I get the following error: ORA-12557: TNS:protocol adapter not loadable.  When in SQL Developer I can see that my connection uses LDAP instead of TNS, so I'm not sure why I have a TNS error (though my knowledge of these protocols are very limited).  Can someone please advise on how to resolve this?

So far I've tried deleting ORACLE_HOME variable below but then I ran into OCI errors, so I reverted back to the original path.

[image]

Comment: TNS is Oracle's networking protocol; ultimately you must have either a TNS or JDBC connection. If you're using LDAP in SQL Developer, that would be as a lookup service to get the TNS connection details. It isn't using LDAP *instead* of TNS, it's using LDAP to get the TNS connection info (hostname, port, service_name, etc.) and then using TNS or JDBC (which can use the same TNS connection descriptors) to open the connection.

Comment: Thanks - Any further suggestions on how to resolve the above issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with EMBLEM specifically, but perhaps this will shed some light: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426915/ora-12557-tnsprotocol-adapter-not-loadable